# How do I remove items from the GRUB menu?

Tags: boot, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to remove/hide old kernel versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-hide-old-kernel-versions)

While booting the system shows two impressions (ubuntu.2.6.38-11-generic and ubuntu 2.6.38-11-generic) are shown in the boot menu. How can I merge them or get rid of the older version?